# Redis sorted set with multiple score "columns"

Tags: redis

I have a need for a leaderboard where users are stored with a score AND a percentage of level completeness. I only need to be able to sort by score and get ranks by score.

Using Redis' sorted sets a can easily store users' scores like so:

```
ZADD leaderboard:gamemode1 100 user1
ZADD leaderboard:gamemode1 300 user2
```

however, I am struggelig to figure out, how to best store the percentage values belonging to the scores of `100` and `300`.

Should I do something like this:

```
ZADD leaderboard:gamemode1 100 user1:29.45
```

where the `:29.45` is the percentage for user1's score of `100` in `gamemode1`? I think this will make it complicated to update user1's score for gamemode1 later.

Or should I instead create a hashtable as a book-keeping mechanism, that stores all users' scores and percentages for all gamemodes?

My concern about the hashtable approach is, that if I want to show a leaderboard of ~50 users with their score and percentage values, I will then have to query that hashtable 50 times to get the percentages, after pulling the top50 scores with `ZRANGE`.

Does anyone have any input on how to construct this in a good way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When working with `Sorted Sets`, keep in mind that it has member string unicity.

That means:

```
ZADD game1 100 user1
ZADD game1 90 user1
```

Leaves you with only `90 user1`.

Just a heads-up, I think you've covered that.

For storing the percentage, you could use the decimal part of the score:

```
ZADD leaderboard:gamemode1 100.0995 user1
ZADD leaderboard:gamemode1  90.0850 user2
```

Above, I use the decimal part for the percentage like this: 0.0995 = 99.5%.

You can also use the score for score only, and serialize the member string:

```
ZADD leaderboard:gamemode1 100 [serialized dictionary/dataset]
ZADD leaderboard:gamemode1  90 [serialized dictionary/dataset]
```

If you use JSON or MsgPack, you can always use server-side scripting to update some data within the serialized string.

I would not recommend bookkeeping for this simple scenario, at least not at this stage. You can always implement that when needed.

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: +1 for the decimal trick. It helps keeping a unique user. Note that the second example will not store a unique user, but will let the same user to be stored multiple times with different percentage, because Redis won't remove the serialized value with different percentage.

Comment: @TechWisdom Well of course. That's why I started with the caveat about "member string unicity".